# Docker-compose containers cannot send request to each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two container in docker-compose. 1- Api 2- web
Webcliet cannot send request to Api directly.web must work on port 80801 https and Api must work on port 8080 http.

When I open web with https://localhost:80801/ , it goes on debug until web call Api with this address: http://Api:8080 or http://localhost:8080 and I got connection refused.

Also I cannot open web with https://web:80801/ and http://Api:8080. It gives me dns error.

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  Api:
    container_name: Api
    image: Api
    container_name: Api
    hostname: Api
    domainname: Api.test
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro


  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web
    container_name: web
    hostname: web
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:80801;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=80801
    ports:
      - "80801:80801"

    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    links:
      - Api
```

Dockerfile for web

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80801

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["web/web.csproj", "web/"]
COPY ["ShopVieweModel/ShopVieweModel.csproj", "ShopVieweModel/"]
COPY ["WebFrameWork/WebFrameWork.csproj", "WebFrameWork/"]
COPY ["Common/Common.csproj", "Common/"]
COPY ["Shop.Data/Shop.Data.csproj", "Shop.Data/"]
COPY ["Shop.Entities/Shop.Entities.csproj", "Shop.Entities/"]
COPY ["Shop.Core/Shop.Core.csproj", "Shop.Core/"]
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
COPY ["Shop.Ioc/Shop.Ioc.csproj", "Shop.Ioc/"]
COPY ["ApiTest/ApiTest.csproj", "ApiTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "web/web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/web"
RUN dotnet build "web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "web.dll"]
```

dockerfile for web

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
COPY ["Shop.Entities/Shop.Entities.csproj", "Shop.Entities/"]
COPY ["ShopVieweModel/ShopVieweModel.csproj", "ShopVieweModel/"]
COPY ["Shop.Ioc/Shop.Ioc.csproj", "Shop.Ioc/"]
COPY ["Shop.Core/Shop.Core.csproj", "Shop.Core/"]
COPY ["Common/Common.csproj", "Common/"]
COPY ["Shop.Data/Shop.Data.csproj", "Shop.Data/"]
COPY ["WebFrameWork/WebFrameWork.csproj", "WebFrameWork/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

This is  docker ps result

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
95c9b2a21faf        web:dev       "tail -f /dev/null"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:80801->80801/tcp   web
df52721a9c07        Api:dev         "tail -f /dev/null"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   Api
```

What is wrong in my configs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this for api container

`environment: - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:61947`
And it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

use links or create a network.
this is should helps you:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I added     links:
      - "shopapi:shopapi" . Also created custom bridge network. but it's not working.

Comment: probably you should not use port number on url